# Symfony2 FOSuserBundle event REGISTRATION_COMPLETED is not triggered

Tags: php, symfony, events, registration, fosuserbundle

For my project, I need to redirect the user after registration. In order to achieve that, I created an `EventListener` as described below :

My Event Listener :

```
namespace UserBundle\EventListener;

use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;

class RegistrationConfirmListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $router;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRM => 'onRegistrationConfirm'
        );
    }

    public function onRegistrationConfirm(GetResponseUserEvent $event)
    {
        $url = $this->router->generate('standard_user_registration_success');
        $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
    }
}
```

I registered it as a service in my service.yml :

```
services:
    rs_user.registration_complet:
        class: UserBundle\EventListener\RegistrationConfirmListener
        arguments: [@router]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

And I need to use it in my RegistrationController but I don't understand how to trigger it.
Here in my `registerAction` :

```
public function registerAction(Request $request)
{
        $em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        //Form creation based on my user entity
        $user = new StandardUser();
        $form = $this->createForm(RegistrationStandardUserType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $user       ->setEnabled(true);
            $em         ->persist($user);
            $em         ->flush();
            if ($user){
                $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');
                $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRM);
            }
        }

    return $this->render('UserBundle:Registration:register.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

I don't understand the [Symfony2 documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher.html) about the subject neither what I need to pass to the `->dispatch()` function to trigger my event.

[EDIT]
I get this error when I register my user :

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to
UserBundle\EventListener\RegistrationConfirmListener::onRegistrationConfirm()
must be an instance of UserBundle\EventListener\GetResponseUserEvent,
instance of Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event given
500 Internal Server Error - FatalThrowableError
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your listener declares that it is subscribed to `FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRM` but you are dispatching `FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED`. To trigger it you need to dispatch a `FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRM` event

edit to match your edit, you need to pass the event in your services `tags`:

```
- { name: 'kernel.event_subscriber', event: 'fos_user.registration.confirm'}
```

Comment: My bad, but I already tried it an got an error, I updated my post (sorry for the waste of time)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the update. The event is now passed as described in your post but I still have the error. I think it could be the way I dispatch it but still, I have no idea ...

Comment: You can remove the declaration in your method to ensure the method runs even if it's not the exact event object you expected. i.e. instead of `public function onRegistrationConfirm(GetResponseUserEvent $event)` do `public function onRegistrationConfirm($event)` - or declare the event it is returning, based on what you're doing either should be okay

Comment: Doing this, I get : Attempted to call an undefined method named "setResponse" of class "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event". on my listener. I now know my eventListener is triggered and I just need to do the redirection

Comment: edited one more time, i was confusing the wrong event tag name. it's `fos_user.registration.confirm`

Comment: Dont bother, as i said in my last coment,  this is not the main problem. I get an error and I dont know how to pass the right args